# A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'. OData 2.2

Tags: kendo-ui, odata

Kendo Filter

```
if ($.trim(DepartmentId)) { $filter.push({ field: "DepartmentId", operator: "eq", value: DepartmentId  }); }
```

Model

```
public System.Guid DepartmentId { get;  set; }
```

Method

```
[Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Employee> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)
    {
        EmployeeService.HrEmployeeServiceFacadeClient emp = new EmployeeService.HrEmployeeServiceFacadeClient();
        var response = emp.GetAll();
        List<Employee> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(response.Result);
        var resultString = result.AsQueryable();

        return resultString;
    }
```

I'm Using OData 2.2

Its showing Error

A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'.

Answer (score 4):

In OData v2, a literal GUID must be serialized as `guid'dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd'` where each `d` represents a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.",

Comment: /AccountSet?$filter=AccountId eq guid'03a0a47b-e3a2-e311-9402-00155d104c22'